# problems with text alignment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout

i have a problem with the output of my code, when I use `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` the text is not aligned as indicated

This is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/press"
        android:textColor="@color/purple_200"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
</Linear Layout>
```

the result photo:
[image: the result photo]

code photo:
[image: code photo]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/press"
        android:textColor="@color/purple_200"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

1. Your ending bracket had an unnecessary space `</Linear Layout>`
2. Use layout_gravity instead of gravity:

> Layout Gravity affects your position in the superview. Gravity affects the position of your subviews within you.

Comment: Basically, `gravity="center_horizontal"` means how the text is positioned *inside the `TextView`*. But because the `TextView`'s width is set to `wrap_content`, the text just fills it anyway. And by default in a `LinearLayout`, views are aligned to the left/start of the screen. You could make the `TextView` fill the width of the screen (with `match_parent`) and then the text would be visibly centred in the middle of its view. Or you can leave it wrapping to the size of its content, and just place it in the centre of its parent with `layout_gravity` (which is probably what you want)